# How do I force input boxes to display content the same across all devices/browsers?

Tags: html, css, text, passwords

Whats the best practise to have the dots be spaced out evenly across a password div so that they display similar to an IOS lock screen?
My current methods displays differently across browsers but I need something that will be consistent

Heres an image of my current pin box so you can see what its sort of supposed to look like...

[image]

Comment: What is your current method?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please provide an example that reproduces what you are saying? This will help make your question specific enough to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using letter-spacing, e.g.

```
letter-spacing:1em;
```

Though you may find it tricky to get it looking perfectly the same across browsers. Should be able to get it fairly close.

Comment: Yeah that's what my current solution has which works across most browsers except when i try use an IOS device. thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @AReeves That's ok, though please would you be able to post the relevant markup/css for what you've tried so far? That way you'll hopefully get better answers here :)